# Make GET request to Google app engine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, get, arduino

I'm trying to make a get request from Arduino to GAE using PHP.

Arduino code:

```cpp
#define DST_IP "https://myservice-183310.appspot.com" // my gae address

String cmd;
Wifi.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
cmd += DST_IP;
cmd += "\",80\r\n";
Wifi.println(cmd);
if(Wifi.find("OK")){
  Serial.println("LINK SUCCESS");
}
else{
  Serial.println("LINK ERROR");
}

String user_info="GET /register.php?nfc_id=";
user_info+=nfc_id;
user_info+="\r\nHTTP/1.0 HOST: ";
user_info+=DST_IP;
user_info+="\r\n\r\n";

cmd="AT+CIPSEND=";
cmd+=String(user_info.length());
Wifi.println(cmd);
Wifi.print(user_info);
```

app.yaml in GAE:

```yaml
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /register.php
  script: register.php
```

And I get a 404 error message, but `"https://myservice-183310.appspot.com/register.php?nfc_id=ooo"` works in the browser.

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because register.php is not where you think it is in the file system.

Comment: register.php is in the file system. This works fine if I type in url in browser, but I get an error using http request in Arduino

Comment: That's not a valid host. And `HTTP/1.0 HOST` is a not valid header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid HTTP request should look like:

```
GET /request.php?nfc_id=MY_NFC_ID HTTP/1.0
Host: myservice-183310.appspot.com
```

I'm no Arduino coder, but it looks like the request you are sending is:

```
GET /register.php?nfc_id=MY_NFC_ID
HTTP/1.0 HOST: https://myservice-183310.appspot.com
```

Things to note

- The `HTTP/1.0` goes on the same line as the `GET`, not on its own line.
- The `Host:` HTTP header should not have the protocol `https`.  SSL or non-SSL will already have been handled before these headers can be read, so they are unneeded (and so might only cause trouble).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the "HTTPS" protocol, try with "HTTP".